# How to Limit Excerpt Length in $category->description in archive-products.php WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, archive

I would like to have limit excerpt length 30 characters in `echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';` here my code:

```
<?php
    $orderby = 'name';
    $order = 'asc';
    $hide_empty = true ;
    $cat_args = array(
        'orderby'    => $orderby,
        'order'      => $order,
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    );
    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_category', $cat_args );
        if( !empty($product_categories) ){
            echo '<div class="container">';
            echo '<div class="row">';
            foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
                echo '<div class="col-lg-6">';
                echo '<div class="card">';
                echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
                $image = get_field('product_category', $category );
                if($image) {
                    echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] .'">';
                    } else {
                        echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/placeholder.png">';
                    }
                echo '<h3>' . $category->name . '</h3>';
                //echo $category->name;
                echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';
                echo '<button class="button btn_medium btn_orange btn_squared btn_normal_style" href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >Discover more</button>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    else {
        // no posts found
        echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no products were found' );
    }
?>
```

How do I add limit excerpt length in `echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';`?

Thanks,

Shaun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<p>' . mb_strimwidth($category->description, 0, 30, "...") . '</p>'
```

Use [mb_strimwidth()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php) function

This will limit the characters, and add add dots if more then 30 characters.

Comment: Hi @Nawin do I put this `string mb_strimwidth ( string $str , int $start , int $width [, string $trimmarker = "" [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ]] )` into functions.php or in archive-products.php?

Comment: @Bubble Where you display the description? I meant in functions.php or archive.php file?

Comment: in archive-products.php

Comment: @Bubble Then add that line in to archive-products.php

Comment: @Bubble You just Replace this line "echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';" to this line "echo '<p>' . mb_strimwidth($category->description, 0, 30, "...") . '</p>';"

Comment: thanks, how to remove dot in the end of the word e.g now display 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ...' I would like to display 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...' only 3 dots? Thanks :)

Comment: That function is counting total Characters only. So It will work like that @Bubble It is not a problem otherwise you need to use rtrim function before the mb_strimwidth function

Answer (score 0):

You can use sting function substr() the given is the solution you are looing for :

```
<?php $description = $category->description; ?>

<p><?php echo substr($description ,0,30); ?> </p>
```